# mongoose sub document access

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How would you access the sub document on an already found document?

Let's say I create the following models:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const schema = mongoose.Schema;

const barStructure = {
    name: { type: String, require: true }
}

const fooStructure = {
    name: { type: String, require: true },
    bar: { type: schema.ObjectId, ref: 'bar', require: false }
}

var BarModel = mongoose.model('Bar', schema(barStructure));
var FooModel = mongoose.model('Foo', schema(fooStructure));
```

and then create:

```
FooModel.create({ name: 'name', bar: new BarModel({ name: 'name' }) });
```

Now how can I access `bar` from the parent?

```
FooModel.findOne({ name: 'name' }, (err, result) => {
    //How can I access bar here?
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Mongoose [**Query Population**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) feature:

```
fooModel
  .findOne({ name: 'name' })
  .populate('bar')
  .exec((err, foo) => {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log(foo.bar): // Access sub model
  });
```